# https://console.cloud.google.com/ not loading

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

cloud.google.com not opening in any browser on my pc. Even the blue menu bar on top is not showing. Sometimes only my profile picture is showing. basically a blank page is opening. I am writing this error report after complaint mail search in google and finding Stack Exchange. Probably one of my catched memory pages. I was facing the same problem yesterday. On inserting the generated API Key in LeadsGorilla app it is saying 'API key Invalid or can't get response from Google'. Basically the cloud platform is non responsive

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what browser you are using? What else (other browsers) you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I can't experienced this issue on my cloud console.

Try these steps

1. open a incognito window on chrome
2. verify that all chrome extensions are disabled
3. sign into console.cloud.google.com
4. check if you can perform your actions as normal

Some chrome extensions like adblockers or VPN/proxy tunnels, can change the behaviour of the cloud console, because can modify HTML, JS and CSS files .

If this fail try to use another network and device to validate that this is really happening on your GCP project and it is not related with your browser or device configurations.

If you continue having this issue I recommend you to open a [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and a Google Agent will be check your issue.